# Radio button click action in swing

Tags: swing, swingworker

I have 2 radio button as 'yes' and 'no'.
after clicking on yes button i need 3 levels as below in the same frame.

1 what is ur name? ---------

2 ur age? ---------

3 sex? --------

similarly after clicking on no button these levels will not show in the frame.

Please help me to solve this in swing.

I have tried like on clicking the radio button it will show a message in the JOptionPane by showMessageDialog.but unable to solve this one

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: We will help you for sure, but you should try first.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do, is to add the extra components, that you wanted to show on the selection of the `YES JRadioButton`, and put them all on a `JPanel`.

Now on selection of `YES JRadioButton`, simply add this `JPanel` on to the `JPanel, that is holding both the JRadioButton and this newly created JPanel`, and call `frame.pack()`, as shown in the below example.

```
private ActionListener radioActions = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == yesRButton)
        {
            if (!selectionPanel.isShowing())
                contentPane.add(selectionPanel);
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == noRButton)
        {
            if (selectionPanel.isShowing())
                contentPane.remove(selectionPanel);
        }
        frame.pack();
    }
};
```